# Indication that the sales order has been goods issued

Tags: abap, sap-erp

Is there a way to determine if the sales order has already been goods issued? From what table shall I look? There's some advice to me to use **VBAP.VBELN** as where condition for **VBFA.VBELV** then get VBFA.VBELN for which I'm gonna be using to select from VBUP table where VBUP.VBTYP_N = 'J'.

And he said, if it's J, it means, it is already goods issued...

I know that 'J' means delivery. But, is there any other way or simpler way to determine if the sales order has already been goods issued?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The sales order itself doesn't hold a goods movement status. You need to follow the document flow (table VBFA) to first get the delivery numbers for your sales order, then get hold of either the delivery head status (table VBUK) or position status (table VBUP). In table VBUK/VBUP field WBSTK/WBSTA is 'C' if the document/position is completely processed.

Comment: Hi Dirk. What if I join VBAP and VBUP tables? Is VBAP.VBELN differ from VBUP.VBELN?

Comment: Then after joining, I'll be referring to VBUP.WBSTA if EQ to 'C'? (*without accessing VBFA table). \n                                    FROM vbap INNER JOIN vbup
        ON ( vbap~vbeln = vbup~vbeln )
        FOR ALL ENTRIES IN gt_material
        WHERE vbap~matnr EQ gt_material-matnr
        AND vbap~werks   EQ gt_material-loggr
        AND VBUP~WBSTA EA 'C'
        AND vbap~vbeln EQ vbup~vbeln
        AND vbap~posnr EQ vbup~posnr .

Comment: Will this code give correct output? (PGI'd) or MUST access VBFA table??

Comment: VBUK and VBUP contain document status data for several document types. If you want to join VBAP and VBUP and in the end want the goods movement status, you will have to join VBAP to VBFA to get the delivery numbers, then VBFA to VBUP to get the status. Unfortunately there is no single step from one sales order to the goods movement status. And keep in mind that you can (at least in theory) have several deliveries for a single sales order.